# Difference in Days between two Date picker values in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker

I have two datepickers as follows :

```
<input type="date" name ="datepicker_start" id="datepicker" value=""  class="datepicker" size="20" />
```

and

```
<input type="date" name ="datepicker_end" id="datepicker2"  value="" class="datepicker" size="20" />
```

And i want to calculate the difference in days and then compare the difference in days with :

```
<input type="text" name="tleave" value="Var" readonly="true" size="10" />
```

where Var is a variable.

then i need to popup an error message if the difference is greater than "Var" value.

Basically consider it as a Leave Request,when you can set the start and end dates for your leave,but the duration of the leave cannot exceed the Leave balance; if it does,system should notify the user.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: Appreciate that @MarcB  :)

Comment: Will the `tleave` value be a numeric one or do you really mean that the name of a variable is entered there?

Comment: it's a value that will be picked from a php variable actually.

Comment: I think you made your point quite clear, but you did not ask a **question**. What is your problem, where did you struggle? What part of your code is not working as expected?

Comment: i am not sure how to trigger the function which calculate the difference, on second picker change or like form validation??

Comment: also i tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/25/)

Comment: @AhmedAli: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/27/

Comment: @TamilVendhan : i noticed that you put (input type="text"..) and created your own javascript for date picker. this means i can't use : input type ="date" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without unneeded libraries

```
    var start = new Date( $('#datepicker').val() ).getTime(),
        end = new Date( $('#datepicker2').val() ).getTime();

    //1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 1 day = 86400000
    alert( ((end - start) / 86400000) + " days" );
```

Comment: It worked with the jsfiddle Tamil set up. `$('#datepicker').val()` did return a string I think in the form 01/07/2013. `new Date( ... )` returns a Date-object, `.getTime()` will turn that into an int in seconds since epoch. You might want to run it with `Math.ceil( ... )` or `floor` to correct for daylight saving time.

Comment: what do you mean by `type='date'`? The html5 input type?

Answer (score 3):

If you use **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)**, you would do something like this:

```
var start = $('#datepicker').val(),
end = $('#datepicker2').val();

var diffInDays = moment(start).diff(moment(end), 'days');

if(diffInDays > Var) {...}
```

### Update:

I have updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/27/)**.

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker_start" id="datepicker" value="" class="datepicker" size="20" />
<input type="text" name="datepicker_start2" id="datepicker2" value="" class="datepicker" size="20"   />

<button>number of days</button>
```

### JS:

```
$('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker();

$('button').click(function () {
    var start = $('#datepicker').val(),
        end = $('#datepicker2').val();

    var diffInDays = moment(end).diff(moment(start), 'days');

    alert(diffInDays);
});
```

I have changed input type to `text`, since `type='date'` gave unexpected ui in the fiddle.
You have to use jquery datepicker as fallback.

In my fiddle, I used `jQuery` datepicker & `moment.js` a `5.5kb` library to deal with dates.

Comment: (+1) Good solution to deal with dates. Also, [datehs](http://www.datejs.com/) is available for that.

Comment: @Tamil : can you be more detailed please!

Comment: Very Great,but the only thing i can't change my picker is because i am posting the dates to a different application that accept the date in specific format that only type='date' is providing.
plus it will ruin my whole project :/

Comment: Check: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

var startDate = moment(start).format('L');